# CodeBlocks in Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't show any result in Console after Build and Run. What should I do?

Tags: 18.04, compiling, c++, programming, code-blocks

[image: Output from CodeBlocks]

I have just switched to linux.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you installed build-essential? `sudo apt install build-essential` from the command line?

Comment: yes... didn't work :(

Comment: didn't work, as in, the install didn't work or it didn't fix your problem? what does the debug tab say? have you tried to build/run your program from the command line?

Comment: what i meant was that the package was already installed. And it didn't solve the problem I am having with CodeBlocks. (it is not showing the output in console)

Comment: what's in those other tabs? code-blocks, debugger, etc?

Comment: Is `xterm` installed? As I tried to install codeblacks and it needs xterm!

Comment: woah george that was the thing! xterm wasn't installed! you are a life saver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C++ program is not running in Code::Blocks because you do not have a C++ compiler (a version of G++) installed, or if it is installed you have not configured the C++ compiler in the Code::Blocks compiler settings. The C++ compiler is not configured for any version of g++ in Ubuntu 18.04 by default, so it has to be configured in the Code::Blocks compiler settings.

1. Install the latest version of the g++ compiler for C++.

   ```
   sudo apt install g++-8 xterm
   ```

   Optionally install the latest version of gcc too (recommended).

   ```
   sudo apt install gcc-8-base # recommended version
   ```
2. Start Code::Blocks.
3. Select *Settings* -> *Compiler* -> *Global compiler settings* (large blue gear icon in the left pane) -> *Toolchain executables* tab.
4. Select the *Program Files* tab. It has already been selected in the below screenshot.
5. Click the **<kbd>..</kbd>** button(s) which are marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot. Navigate to `/usr/bin`. The *C compiler* should be either `gcc` or optionally `gcc-8`, the *C++ compiler* should be `g++-8` and the *Linker for dynamic libs* should be `g++-8`.
6. Click the     **<kbd>OK</kbd>**     button to close the **Compiler settings** window.

[image]

Comment: did all that... but still no result in console... in the build log, the message is

------------- Run: Debug in hello_linux (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /home/rafid/Desktop/Study Materials/Code/C++/hello_linux/bin/Debug/hello_linux
Executing: xterm -T hello_linux -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /home/rafid/Desktop/Study\ Materials/Code/C++/hello_linux/bin/Debug/hello_linux  (in /home/rafid/Desktop/Study Materials/Code/C++/hello_linux/.)
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: what happens if you change the debugger?

Comment: I think you either have messed up the existing hello project or else you have not yet created a new hello project in Codeblocks. Select File -> New -> Project -> Console application -> click Go button and follow the new project wizard to the end. First delete the old hello project so it doesn't interfere with the new hello project. And type the C++ code in main.cpp from scratch so you don't copy any Windows line endings which don't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: gdb is the default debugger and it always works perfectly in Code::Blocks. You can change the default debugger of course, but that should be asked as a separate question. Let's get this program working with gdb first. Afterwards you can ask how to install a different debugger and configure it in Code::Blocks. Your C++ code in your question is OK, so you won't need gdb yet for this code.

Comment: everything was fine... XTerm was supposed to be installed to show the console... phew who knew...

Comment: wait, so the answer is to install XTERM? as in the answer here is not correct?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte You can't run C++ programs without installing some version of g++, not in Code::Blocks and not even from the terminal. Code::Blocks uses the Intel C/C++ Compiler for compiling C++ code by default, which is not available in the default Ubuntu repositories, so you need to install g++ instead.

Comment: right... but i was more commenting on OPs comment... what actually fixed his problem was installing xterm as the C compilers were already installed when he installed build essential.

Comment: Even if you already have g++ installed, Code::Blocks still won't compile C++ code until you configure it for C++ in the Code::Blocks compiler settings. Code::Blocks was originally written for Windows, so it often tries to do everything the same way it is done in Windows by default until you configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install `codeblocks` in bionic and it was almost a night mare as so many dependencies are needed. In the case of the question OP was missing the `xterm terminal` that `codeblocks` uses to work and that can be found in the `libwxbase3.0-0v5` package, when you try to install this it will complain then you run `sudo apt install -f` and it will install `xterm` as part of the dependencies.

[image]

Please note that the `codeblocks` download comes with the dependencies needed in the archive file`codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz` from their down load site.

Comment: seems like this is the actual correct answer....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ur problem is that you saved the file in the default format (.ads) provided by codeblocks. I had the same problem but solved it after I renamed my file extension from .ads to .cpp.

Hope this helps