# How to install eclipse c++ In Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++

This is a similar question asked on Aug 16 but the answer given did not fix the problem.  I am brand new to Ubuntu and have tried following several different sets of instructions for installing eclipse and still can't get the hello world application to compile and run.  With the set of instructions on Aug 16, I get "nothing to build for project..." error.

Since I'm new to linux and ubuntu the previous answers to this problem are unclear and assume a lot of knowledge about the way ubuntu installs and links programs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm astonished that so many users report that Eclipse C/C++ can't do a simple thing like run a hello world console application in Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe try a few different things besides wringing out Eclipse. I use Visual Studio Code with the C/C++ and Code Runner extensions most of the time. Unfortunately C/C++ things that work out of the box for me sometimes don't work at all for brand new users at Ask Ubuntu. Did you also install `sudo apt install g++` ? [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1066155/94914) works in 18.04 too.

Comment: It appears I had not installed the compiler.  Thanks for the help.  I finally got it to work by doing sudo apt install g++ followed by sudo apt-get install make

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse official website, search for "Download packages" link somewhere and then download "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers". It'll be an archive, probably a *.tar.gz. Extract that archive, launch eclipse from the directory.

I haven't seen anyone regularly packaging Eclipse into deb packages for apt-get. So downloading from the site has become the easiest option. Adding the fact that Eclipse is like a mini-OS with its own built-in package manager I rely on the official site to assemble the correct configuration for the task (the C++ development in this case).